# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, veeam

my vm backup job is failing with

```
**Job Error**: Failed to create snapshot for LUN NL_Raid6b Details: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

**VM Error**:  Failed to prepare VM for processing from storage snapshot, failing over to using VM snapshot.

23/07/2019 01:30:12 :: Job started at 23/07/2019 01:30:06  
23/07/2019 01:30:13 :: Building list of machines to process  
23/07/2019 01:30:39 :: VM size: 798.5 GB  
23/07/2019 01:30:39 :: Changed block tracking is enabled  
23/07/2019 01:30:43 :: Queued for processing at 23/07/2019 01:30:44  
23/07/2019 01:30:43 :: Required backup infrastructure resources have been assigned  
23/07/2019 01:31:18 :: Creating storage snapshot  
23/07/2019 01:31:20 :: Failed to create snapshot for LUN NL_Raid6b Details: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.  
23/07/2019 01:31:29 :: Processing myvm-7  
23/07/2019 01:31:34 :: Processing myvm-6  
23/07/2019 01:32:45 :: Processing myvm-3  
23/07/2019 01:34:00 :: Processing myvm-5  
23/07/2019 01:35:26 :: Processing myvm-2  
23/07/2019 01:36:56 :: Processing myvm-8  
23/07/2019 01:39:01 :: Processing myvm  
23/07/2019 01:41:17 :: Processing myvm-4  
23/07/2019 01:42:37 :: All VMs have been queued for processing  
23/07/2019 01:45:42 :: Load: Source 35% > Proxy 80% > Network 12% > Target 0%  
23/07/2019 01:45:42 :: Primary bottleneck: Proxy  
23/07/2019 01:45:42 :: Job finished with warning at 23/07/2019 01:45:42   

----------

myvm-4

23/07/2019 01:30:57 :: Creating VM snapshot  
23/07/2019 01:31:01 :: Collecting disk files location data  
23/07/2019 01:31:20 :: Failed to prepare VM for processing from storage snapshot, failing over to using VM snapshot.  
23/07/2019 01:31:21 :: Removing VM snapshot  
23/07/2019 01:31:29 :: Queued for processing at 23/07/2019 01:31:30  
23/07/2019 01:31:30 :: Required backup infrastructure resources have been assigned  
23/07/2019 01:42:38 :: VM processing started at 23/07/2019 01:42:38  
23/07/2019 01:42:38 :: VM size: 124.0 GB (87.5 GB used)  
23/07/2019 01:42:38 :: Getting VM info from vSphere  
23/07/2019 01:42:44 :: Creating VM snapshot  
23/07/2019 01:42:59 :: Saving [vfs-sto01-san-04(NL)] myvm-4/myvm-4.vmx  
23/07/2019 01:42:59 :: Saving [vfs-sto01-san-04(NL)] myvm-4/myvm-4.nvram  
23/07/2019 01:43:00 :: Using backup proxy VMware Backup Proxy for disk Hard disk 1 [san]  
23/07/2019 01:43:00 :: Using backup proxy VMware Backup Proxy for disk Hard disk 2 [san]  
23/07/2019 01:43:01 :: Hard disk 1 (64.0 GB) 1.3 GB read at 20 MB/s [CBT] 
23/07/2019 01:43:01 :: Hard disk 2 (20.0 GB) 1.3 GB read at 18 MB/s [CBT] 
23/07/2019 01:44:20 :: Using backup proxy VMware Backup Proxy for disk Hard disk 3 [san]  
23/07/2019 01:44:21 :: Hard disk 3 (40.0 GB) 191.0 MB read at 41 MB/s [CBT] 
23/07/2019 01:44:35 :: Removing VM snapshot  
23/07/2019 01:44:40 :: Finalizing  
23/07/2019 01:44:47 :: Busy: Source 99% > Proxy 27% > Network 3% > Target 0%  
23/07/2019 01:44:47 :: Primary bottleneck: Source  
23/07/2019 01:44:47 :: Network traffic verification detected no corrupted blocks  
23/07/2019 01:44:47 :: Processing finished with warnings at 23/07/2019 01:44:48  



myvm-5

23/07/2019 01:30:57 :: Creating VM snapshot  
23/07/2019 01:31:01 :: Collecting disk files location data  
23/07/2019 01:31:20 :: Failed to prepare VM for processing from storage snapshot, failing over to using VM snapshot.  
23/07/2019 01:31:21 :: Removing VM snapshot  
23/07/2019 01:31:29 :: Queued for processing at 23/07/2019 01:31:30  
23/07/2019 01:31:30 :: Required backup infrastructure resources have been assigned  
23/07/2019 01:35:26 :: VM processing started at 23/07/2019 01:35:26  
23/07/2019 01:35:26 :: VM size: 104.0 GB (97.1 GB used)  
23/07/2019 01:35:26 :: Getting VM info from vSphere  
23/07/2019 01:35:33 :: Creating VM snapshot  
23/07/2019 01:35:44 :: Saving [vfs-sto01-san-04(NL)] myvm-5/myvm-5.vmx  
23/07/2019 01:35:44 :: Saving [vfs-sto01-san-04(NL)] myvm-5/myvm-5.nvram  
23/07/2019 01:35:45 :: Using backup proxy VMware Backup Proxy for disk Hard disk 1 [san]  
23/07/2019 01:35:45 :: Using backup proxy VMware Backup Proxy for disk Hard disk 2 [san]  
23/07/2019 01:35:47 :: Hard disk 1 (64.0 GB) 1.9 GB read at 17 MB/s [CBT] 
23/07/2019 01:35:47 :: Hard disk 2 (20.0 GB) 2.5 GB read at 18 MB/s [CBT] 
23/07/2019 01:42:12 :: Using backup proxy VMware Backup Proxy for disk Hard disk 3 [san]  
23/07/2019 01:42:13 :: Hard disk 3 (20.0 GB) 854.0 MB read at 61 MB/s [CBT] 
23/07/2019 01:42:37 :: Removing VM snapshot  
23/07/2019 01:43:50 :: Finalizing  
23/07/2019 01:43:57 :: Busy: Source 99% > Proxy 29% > Network 2% > Target 0%  
23/07/2019 01:43:57 :: Primary bottleneck: Source  
23/07/2019 01:43:57 :: Network traffic verification detected no corrupted blocks  
23/07/2019 01:43:57 :: Processing finished with warnings at 23/07/2019 01:43:57
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the specifics of your application or infrastructure, however most certificate validation procedures share common aspects.

1. Certificate presence; ensure a valid client certificate exists.
2. Certificate validity; ensure it the client certificate has not expired.
3. Trusted root; ensure the issued certificate's root certificate is trusted by the validating machine.
4. Revocation check; ensure that the issued, valid client certificate's Certificate Revocation List (CRL) can be reached by the validating machine.

Item #2 is a likely culprit if this procedure has been working prior to now and no other configuration changes have occurred. Items #3 and #4 tend to be the biggest issue in certificate validation in environments where the issuing Certificate Authority is internal, such as when using Active Directory Certificate Services authorities.